# Laravel: Check if a field exists in database only if it is present in request

Tags: laravel, validation, request, exists

I want to validate a form in Laravel.

I want to check if a field exists in database only if it is present in request.
When User filled the field in the form I what to check if the field exists in database, but if the User did not fill the field I want to exclude de "exists" validation.

Could anybody help me?

Nicolas

Comment: so you want to add the `sometimes` rule?  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#validating-when-present

Comment: I've tried "field_id" => "sometimes|exists:table,id"      But It doesn't work. I always get Selected field_id is invalid.... :-(

Comment: I have to say. The Field is present in request but it is null...

Comment: that is a different thing ... you want to check if it is "present" in the request ... which is what 'sometimes' does, so you need a different rule if it is going to be present but `null`

Comment: Thanks! I've tried with nullable and it works!

Answer (score 0):

```
if($request->has('code')) {
   $query = User::all()->get('code');
   if ($request->code!= $query){
       $alert = array(
           'message' => 'Wrong referral code passed!',
           'alert-type' => 'invalid-code');
       return back()->with($alert);
   }
```

Comment: This query will check in the database to see if the code coming from the input field exist in the database. If doesn't exist the query will throw an error. If nothing is entered in the field too the query will be ignored.